# Should Answer updates be added to the top or bottom of the answer?

Tags: discussion, edits, answers

I update my answers from time to time as new information rolls in. Should the new updates be at the top or the bottom of my answers?

I think the bottom would suit a chronological order, but new people seeing the question/answer for the first time might be most interested in the update, not the original answer.

See example at https://stackoverflow.com/a/13525758/694325

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I am looking for a solution to the problem, I do not care about the state of the thing months or years in the past, I want to know what the status is now. I admire the fact that you are diligently updating your answer, and that's great, but the best way to update the answer is to rewrite it to be up-to-date without just tacking stuff on at the bottom.

So right now you have the answer and two updates. It looks like, from what I've read, there is an explanation of the problem, a workaround, and it has finally been fixed in a recent (but unstable) version. I would write it much more simply as:

1. This issue is caused by a bug in the code related to big tables
2. This is fixed in version 0.12 (an unstable release right now)
3. If you use an earlier version, you can try *this workaround*

This makes it easy for anyone who stumbles across the question to identify the cause, figure out the solution for their circumstance, and is a great answer. Keep up the good work!

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the update.

If it is

> “V2.1 now has xxxx that does this; therefore this answer is only of
>   use for people using a past version”

then it should be at the top.

If it is some changes to the details that are correct for all users of the answer, then it should be edited into the answer, no one care that you discovered them later.

If it is details of one “odd” case when you now know that the answer will not work, it might as well go at the end.

**In most cases a complete rewrite is of more value, as per jmax answer, but I would rather be given the additional information even if it is just tacked onto the start or the end of the answer.**